Executing Uniswap router v2 swaps with the least amount of gas
I am trying to execute a bunch of trades for an automated trading service on Base.
Would it be cheaper to use ethers and loop through calling the UniswapV2 router contract or should I execute trades via a custom contract which calls UniswapV2 and swaps in the contract?   Possibly the custom contract could also take a list of addresses[] in which need to make the swap.
And if I do it this in a custom contract should I do this all in a constructor including looping through address[] and calling swapExactETHForTokens.
Looking for any tips to do this in the most optimized way.

Typically, cross-contract calls consume more gas. I don't know how your setup exactly look like, so it possibly might be safer to use a custom contract to do the trades (for example, how do you manage the private keys in your setup for the different trades?). It also depends on how many trades you want to perform - if there are many, you might run into gas limit issues if a contract is supposed to perform all these trades in one transaction. If you decide to create your custom contract, you wouldn't do this in the constructor since the constructor only runs once during contract deployment.
